# Progressbar выкидывает java.lang.NullPointerException, где ошибка?

Tags: java, android

Предполагаю что дело в модификаторах доступа, но не могу понять почему `pbHealth.setProgress(a)` выдает `NullPointerException`?

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressBar pbHealth;
static int progressHealth, maxProgressHealth;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    pbHealth = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbHealth);

    progressHealth = pbHealth.getProgress();
    maxProgressHealth = pbHealth.getMax();

}

public int getHealthProgress() {
    return progressHealth;
}
public void setHealthProgress(int a) {
    pbHealth.setProgress(a); //ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ВЫБРАСЫВАЕТ ОШИБКУ!!!
}
public int getHealthMax() {
    return maxProgressHealth;
}
}
```

Второй Класс:

```
public class Tab1_Action extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

View rootView;
MyActivity main;

RelativeLayout btnSleep;
static int addHealth;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_action, container, false);

    main = new MyActivity();
    return rootView;
}
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnSleep:
            if (main.getHealthProgress() < main.getHealthMax())
            {
                main.setHealthProgress(main.getHealthProgress() + addHealth); //ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ПРОИСХОДИТ ВЫЗОВ МЕТОДА В КОТОРОМ ОШИБКА!!!
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Потому что `main = new MyActivity();` не вызывает метод `onCreate` и следовательно pbHealth не инициализирован.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `main = new MyActivity();` не вызывает метод `onCreate` и следовательно pbHealth не инициализирован.

Из фрагменте можно получить доступ к элементу активити:

```
ProgressBar pbHealth = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pbHealth);
```

А дальше делайте что хотите с ним.